# .NET MVC Fire and Forget Method also return View immediately

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm looking on best solution for Fire & Forget a method at the Action and return View immediately. So far as i can see if i make the Action's return type `Task<ActionResult>` and `await` the asynchronous method it will work but Action is also waiting that asynchronous method to done before return View as **expected**.

In the other hand if i don't `await` the asynchronous method, method's execution will be cut after the `View` returns.

I'm asking for what's the best solution for situation like that ? My code is like that :

```
public class DefaultController : Controller
{
    // GET: Default
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        await Asynchronous();
        return View();
    }
    public async Task Asynchronous()
    {
        var FilePath = ControllerContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/HelloWorld.txt");
        for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(15000); // Wait 15 Seconds.
            System.IO.File.AppendAllLines(FilePath, new string[] { i.ToString() });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using .NET 4.5.2 or later, you might be able to use the `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm looking on best solution for Fire & Forget a method at the Action and return View immediately

That depends on what "best" means. Fire and Forget on ASP.NET is inherently unsafe, so there are varying degrees of how safe you want your code to be.

If your app *must* continue execution, then the only safe system is to have your action handler write what it wants to do into a safe storage mechanism (e.g., Azure Queue, MSMQ, or SQL Server). Once it has been safely stored, then your action method can return. Then you'll also have an independent background process (e.g., Azure Function, Win32 Service, or possibly a thread in your ASP.NET process only if you're very careful about how it's hosted). That background process will read from the safe storage and do the actual work.

If your app is fine with occasionally "losing" work (after returning success to the client), then you can use a less-safe mechanism such as `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` for .NET 4.5.2, or my [AspNetBackgroundTasks library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AspNetBackgroundTasks) for earlier versions.

Other alternatives are listed in [my blog post on the subject](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).