# Sending back the control to UI and do the rest on the server side without having users to wait

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parallel-processing, .net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have an HTTOPOST action in my API controller which gets an object and persists it to DB and also sends an email out to recipients once the persistence has occurred. The problem is the user needs to wait until the email sending function runs and completes and get their UI back. How can I delegate the act of sending emails to the server and just return the UI to the user after the obj gets persisted? (the users shouldn't be waiting for the email sending to happen.)

```
  [HttpPost("add")]
    public async Task Add(objSaveModel obj)
    {
        Model model = _mapper.Map<Model>(objSaveModel);
        Model createdModel = await _repo.AddModel(model);


        try //sending an email - prior to this action the control needs 
              //to be diverted to the user and the server needs to perform 
              //this asynchronously.
        {
            EmailTemplate emailTemplate = await _repo.GetEmailTemplate();
            MailMessage msg = new 
            ModelNotificationHelper().GenerateNotification(Model, of, 
            emailTemplate);

            if (msg != null)
            {
                new EmailHelper(_emailSettings).Send(msg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

after _repo.AddModel(model); the control needs to be diverted to the UI and the end user, however, it waits for the email sending to happen completely and then the UI gets updated. This is causing an unnecessary delay for the UI. How can I implement this asynchronously/in parallel so both tasks get done without any waiting for the user side?

Comment: Just offload it to a task, however if you want to return notification to the user when it does finish, then that is a different problem. However this sounds like a Client Side issue more than a server side one

Comment: How to offload it to a task? can you write a pseudo code for me?

Comment: you basically just wrap it in a `Task.Run`, however before you do this, maybe its your clients that need to change the way they do things?

Comment: Have a look at something like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). Also, I'm not sure, but when you create a task with `Task.Run`, this task can be disposed by GC at the end of your controller action.

Comment: @TheGeneral the client is an Angular service:      
                     add(obj: Obj) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + 'obj/add', obj);
  }

Comment: @vasily.sib the thread-pool has a reference to it, so it wont be GC'ed,, however your app-pool can be torn down in various circumstances

Answer (score 0):

You want to get behaviour that looks like as the pattern 'fire & forget' (another words, initiate some action without waiting for it will be completed) - it is possible but not safe. Look at these resources to dive the theme: [.NET MVC Fire and Forget Method also return View immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41314202/303298) and [Fire and Forget on ASP.NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

The straight-line way to resolve your problem may rely on [ASP.NET Core Queued Background Tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2#queued-background-tasks).

**Controller**

It just need to 'schedule' a sending email job. Jobs will be processed by background worker.

```
public Controller(IEmailJobQueue emailJobQueue) {
  _emailJobQueue = emailJobQueue;
}

[HttpPost("add")]
public async Task Add(objSaveModel obj)
{
    Model model = _mapper.Map<Model>(objSaveModel);
    Model createdModel = await _repo.AddModel(model);

    await _emailJobQueue.EnqueueJobAsync(new EmailJob("user@stack.com", 11 /* template id */));
}
```

[**Background service**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2#queued-background-tasks):

This implementation uses the in-memory storage, probably you need to consider more reliable and distributed storage such as database, queue etc

```
public sealed EmailJob {
  public EmailJob(string recipientAddress, int emailTemplateId, ..){
    // ..
  }

  // ..
}

public interface IEmailJobQueue
{
    Task EnqueueJobAsync(EmailJob job);
    Task<EmailJob> DequeueJobAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken);
}

public class InMemoryEmailJobQueue : IEmailJobQueue
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<EmailJob> _jobs = new ConcurrentQueue<EmailJob>();

    public Task EnqueueJobAsync(EmailJob job)
    {
        if (job == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(workItem));
        }

        _jobs.Enqueue(job);

        return Task.Completed;
    }

    public Task<EmailJob> DequeueJobAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!_jobs.TryDequeue(out var job){
          return Task.FromResult<EmailJob>(null);
        }

        return Task.FromResult(job);
    }
}

public class EmailSenderService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public EmailSenderService(IEmailJobQueue emailJobQueue, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _emailJobQueue = emailJobQueue;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<QueuedHostedService>();
    }

    public IEmailJobQueue _emailJobQueue { get; }

    protected async override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            var job = await _emailJobQueue.DequeueAsync(cancellationToken);

            if (job == null) {
              Task.Delay(512);
              continue;
            }

            try
            {
                // .. sending email based on data from 'job'
                // Don't forget to handle case when sending fails - either use [Polly.RetryPolicy] (https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry) or persist failed job to postponed processing.
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, $"Error occurred executing {nameof(job)}.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Registration in *Startup.cs***

```
services.AddHostedService<EmailSenderService>();
services.AddSingleton<IEmailJobQueue, InMemoryEmailJobQueue>();
```